# javax.sound.sampled multithread-safe

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

I am working on a simple program that records and playback audio, using java's javax.sound.sampled package. 
I can't find any mention in the java 8 reference if Line(TargetDataLine & SourceDataLine) is threadsafe. This is especially a problem in playback(using SourceDataLine) when both write and drain methods blocks and seems not to respond to thread interruptions.

Can i close a Line instance from another thread to get the original thread to release from a blocking drain or write method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, I only access a SourceDataLine via flagging the class where it resides. The wrapping class is given a public volatile boolean called 'running' and the loop where the SDL resides is surrounded by a `while(running)` condition. The latency that occurs with this approach will vary with the size of the buffer being written.

You might want to add additional flags. But in any event, the while loop around the SDL seems to be an opportune point for interpreting and acting on those flags.